# Regex search: Why C-M-s does not seem to work like other keystrokes?

Tags: isearch, keystrokes

The purpose of this question is primarily to serve my curiosity, but it can maybe save some time for others who may press `C-M-s` (`isearch-forward-regexp`) just like they would press `C-s` (`isearch-forward`), but who would see nothing happening.

In fact, when I press `C-M-s` just like I would for any other keystroke, nothing happens, and I lately figured out I had to **hold it pressed for about half a second for it to work**.

This is also the case if I want to get the description of `C-M-s` using `C-h k`.

What is the reason for that? Is it related to my configuration?

Comment: To test whether it is related to your configuration, try starting emacs as `emacs -Q` under both terminal and graphical environments. I guess the keys could conceivably be intercepted by the terminal emulator or window manager.

Comment: @Basil Did you mean "`emacs -q`" ?

Comment: No, but you can try that too; `-Q` implies `-q` in addition to disabling other custom initialisation code that may be installed on your system. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html) for more information.

Comment: After trying starting Emacs that way (both with and without GUI), the result is the same. Only with the `-Q` option the GUI window is minimized when I press `C-M-s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was apparently due to Ubuntu (with Unity): `C-M-s` was in my case a default key-binding for minimizing windows.

Hence a conflict, I guess. Redefining it to something else solved the problem.

Comment: This is the Ticket that documents the bug in Unity and some workarounds: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1313446

In particulart these comments were useful:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1313446/comments/3 and 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1313446/comments/49

Answer (score 2):

`C-h f isearch-forward-regexp`, then you will find:

> C-M-s (translated from C-M-S-s) runs the command

`C-M-S-s` works(GNU Emacs 25.1.1) for me.